# SQL Sproc Parameters: Setting Default Date value

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, reporting

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure that will be used for a Report and I want the 2 date parameters to have a DEFAULT value of today's date and 1 month prior.

Is the below the proper way to do this?  I was reading elsewhere that I should use COALESCE...([SEE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470664/sql-function-as-default-parameter-value/470670#470670))This is a touchy production system so I wanted to double check before I went forward.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCaseNoteReport 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ContactStartDate DateTime = null,
@ContactEndDate DateTime = null
AS
IF @ContactStartDate is null
SET @ContactStartDate = dateadd(m,-1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
IF @ContactEndDate is null
SET @ContactEndDate = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT (id.LastName + ', ' + id.FirstName) AS 'MemberName'
      ,c.ContactDate
      ,Li.ItemDescription AS 'Location'
      ,c.PresentAtContact
      ,c.ContactDetails   
      ,c.InsertUser
      ,c.TimeSpentUnits

FROM dbo.tblCaseNotes c
    inner join dbo.tblIdentificationMap id
        on c.PersonID = id.PersonID
    left outer join dbo.tblCaseNoteContactLocation L
        on c.Casenoteid = L.Casenoteid
            inner join dbo.tblCaseNotesMaintItem Li
                on L.ContactLocationID = Li.ItemID

WHERE c.ContactDate BETWEEN @ContactStartDate AND @ContactEndDate

ORDER BY MemberName, c.ContactDate, c.InsertUser
```

END

---

### continued

So when I actually tried to run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` for this I get the following errors -->

`Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCaseNoteReport, Line 12
Type date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCaseNoteReport, Line 14
Type date is not a defined system type.`

Comment: Change it to DateTime or just remove the convert since getdate() already returns a datetime.

Comment: That is strange since I got that from MSDN, here -->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx
and towards the bottom, Section B, it clearly shows that exact syntax...

Comment: The Date and Time types are new with sql 2008.

Comment: @DyingCactus:  I am not sure I understand what you mean.  The MSDN link is for `SQL 2005` which is also what I am using.

Comment: The "sql 2005" there is a link to go to the sql 2005 doc for getdate().  The page itself is for sql 2008.  Here is a list of types in sql 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752(SQL.90).  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/jongallant/archive/2008/08/15/new-sql-server-date-datatypes-date-time-datetime2-datetimeoffset.aspx

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: the SQL 2005 link is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383(SQL.90).aspx as per the text/link "Other versions are also available for the following: SQL Server 2005" on your link

Comment: Ahh, thank you both for clearing that up.  Makes much more sense now.  So in 2005 is `CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),101)` the accepted norm then?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

Comment: Since you want to set a datetime variable, just say SET @ContactStartDate = dateadd(m,-1, GETDATE()) and SET @ContactEndDate = GETDATE().  No conversions needed.

Comment: Sorry, you probably want to start at 00:00 so you'll need to use gbn's example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this approach. I use it myself.

Parameter defaults can only be constants or udfs so the alternative is to use udfs which honestly doesn't really help.

Edit: best way to remove a time component from datetime

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

See this excellent SO Q+A ["Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime) (not mine!)