# Clarification of the NewID() function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

I have a stored procedure which accepts two parameters of type `UniqueIdentifier`

When I call this sproc with an explicit call to `NewId()` in place of one of the arguments:

```
exec dbo.TestArgs newid, '34131101-04DE-4B97-8FAC-49C924F7BFCE'
```

it fails with:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

But passing a variable populated by `NewId()` into the call is fine:

```
DECLARE @painInTheArse UniqueIdentifier
SET @painInTheArse = NewID()
```

`EXEC dbo.TestArgs`<strike>`newid`</strike>`@painInTheArse,'34131101-04DE-4B97-8FAC-49C924F7BFCE'`

works perfectly

To me this just seems very wrong. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters passed into stored procs have to be constants. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470664/sql-function-as-default-parameter-value).

Your solution of putting the result of the function call into a parameter first is absolutely correct...

Comment: Great. Thanks v. much. This is because NewID() is deterministic, right?

Comment: Nope newid is nondeterministic, as is getdate(), but any function call in this context will get chucked out by SQL. I'd be interested in hearing from a SQL guru why that is...

Comment: GETDATE() is not deterministic because it is always called with the same arguments, but the results are different every time. This is the reason it (or any non deterministic) function can't be used within a UDF.

Comment: @Wil - yep, and so is newid() no? But in this instance we're talking about why you can't use a function as a parameter when calling a stored proc etc. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: It's the same reason - stored procedure parameters need to be literals or variables, and newid() is a nondeterministic function. It wouldn't work with a deterministic function either. But if you want to see something trippy, watch this:

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.testnewid(@NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
RETURN @NewID
END

SELECT  dbo.testnewid(NEWID())

Comment: @Timbo - It's on the "TODO" list. [Vote for this connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)

Comment: (Sheepishly) I think I meant nondeterministic.

@Wil - can you provide a little commentary on the function you posted?

Comment: Yeah...while you can't call a nondeterministic function from within a function, you can call a nondeterministic function with a nondeterministic function as a parameter. :)

Comment: @Wil - ha, nice one, you learn something every day...tho some things (like that) you sometimes wish you'd never learned... ;)