# CRLF sequence as default parameter value in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 to have a default value specified for one of its parameters. I want this value to be a CRLF sequence. Obviously SQL Server does not allow me to do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProc
   @arg1 nvarchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),
   @arg2
...
```

I know I could write this sequence simply as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProc
   @arg1 nvarchar(2) = '
',
   @arg2
...
```

but it seems... not quite right. What if I send this script to someone via e-mail and CRLF gets converted to LF? Or some space is accidentally added? Or finally, what if I want some other sequence (let it be any Unicode character)?

Using variable to store default value is not an option, as there is no place to declare and initialize variable since `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be first statement in a batch.

Also using `EXEC` on statement string is obviously too troublesome.

Is there any better way to allow sequence of non-printable ASCII/Unicode characters as default value for stored procedure parameter?

Comment: I don't suppose it's an option to make the default an empty string, and then as the first line of the proc, just test for "if the parameter is empty string, set it to CRLF"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470664/sql-function-as-default-parameter-value

Comment: @pmbAustin, no, as it is .NET CLR procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProc
   @arg1 nvarchar(2) =  0x0D000A00 --CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Running the code below returns "is equal" :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProc
   @arg1 nvarchar(2) =  0x0D000A00 
AS    
declare @v nvarchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

IF @arg1 = @v
select 'is equal'
ELSE
select 'is not equal'
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc
```

To work out what hex sequence you should use, you can do something like:

```
declare  @arg1 nvarchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
select cast(@arg1 as varbinary(max))
```

which returns:

```
0x0D000A00
```

Comment: Simply brilliant! I didn't event think of that I could assign binary data to nvarchar without `CONVERT`.