# How to pass GETDATE (Only date) as a parameter in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to pass the system date (`GETDATE`) only as a parameter in my SQL stored procedure. But I am getting an error while executing the procedure.

**SQL query:**

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE ST_PRO_GETUSER
  @D DATETIME = GETDATE  --// passing GETDATE as a parameter.
  AS BEGIN
    select case when branch in ('A25','B10','C10')  
    then 'BR B1' Else 'BR B2' 
    end As [COLLECTION],FIXDATE 
    from MAIN_COUNTER where TDATE=@D  --//Just want to pass date only
    group by COLLECTION,FIXDATE 
 END

 EXEC KK_SP_GETUSER_DIV
```

**Error:**

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What I have to do for it?

Comment: A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470664/sql-function-as-default-parameter-value).

Comment: You're not passing it as a parameter - you're using it as a default for when no parameter is passed.

Comment: Do u have any solution.. how to pass getdate as a parameter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved My Self**

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE ST_PRO_GETUSER
     @Date datetime = null
     as
     IF @Date is null
     SET @Date = getdate()  --// passing GETDATE as a parameter.
      BEGIN
       select case when branch in ('A25','B10','C10')  
       then 'BR B1' Else 'BR B2' 
       end As [COLLECTION],FIXDATE 
       from MAIN_COUNTER where TDATE=@D  --//Just want to pass date only
       group by COLLECTION,FIXDATE 
     END

EXEC ST_PRO_GETUSER
```

Comment: Thats not passing a parameter, thats handling *no* parameter being passed.

Comment: are you saying that your stored procedure is working now ? No syntax error ?

Answer (score 1):

To pass as a parameter you just declare a variable and pass it in:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = GETDATE();
EXEC ST_PRO_GETUSER @DATE;
```

And if you want the date only, change the datatype of your parameter to a `date` and then do:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE = GETDATE();
EXEC ST_PRO_GETUSER @DATE;
```

But part of your question seems to actually be asking how to specify a default parameter value. You can't use a function for the default value, so instead do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ST_PRO_GETUSER
(
    @Date DATETIME = null
    -- Change to DATE datatype if you don't want a time component.
    -- @Date DATE = null
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Default the @Date here is its null.
    -- Note this doesn't handle the case when the caller wants to pass in null.
    SET @Date = COALESCE(@Date,GETDATE());

    -- SP Body

    RETURN 0;
END
```

Answer (score -2):

`GETDATE()` is the correct syntax, not `GETDATE`.

Comment: when i use GETDATE() i get error: Must declare the scalar variable "@D".